# opening a python file as an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with the following in it:

```
[{'page': 0, 'text': 'blah'},{'page': 1, 'text': 'blah'}]
```

I'd like to restore this file to an array of dictionaries, but I'm struggling.

I've tried to use `js = json.loads(data)` to turn it into a dictionary
and I've also tried to load it as a string and then split it (but unsure of how to split--based on '[', ']' brackets.

Ideally it would be read as an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eval` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to parse lists from text.

```python
data = eval(file.read())

print(data[0]["page"])

# Prints "0".
```

Comment: Why use eval when ast.literal_eval works and is safer?